# Make a put request with javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am following this boilerplate code (https://github.com/jkat98/benm) I have gotten the hang of the structure pretty good, I like it. The author did not include an update method/PUT request to the mongodb server. He says this step is a little more complicated, so I am hoping I can show you the main routing and logic of sending data to the server and possibly get some help implementing PUT requests.

So In my opinion there are 3 or 4 key files here that make the magic happen.

A. in `app/models.js`, defining the model for mongodb.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Message = new Schema({
    username:    { type: String },
    message:     { type: String },
    connected:   { type: Boolean },
    sent:        { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = {
    Message: mongoose.model('Message', Message)
};
```

B. In `app/routes.js` Creating the routes for the api.

```
var home = require('../controllers/home'),
    messages = require('../controllers/messages');

module.exports.initialize = function(app) {
    app.get('/', home.index);

    // Messages
    app.get('/api/messages', messages.index);
    app.get('/api/messages/:id', messages.getById);
    app.post('/api/messages', messages.add);

    // Having a hard time with the PUT request
    app.put('/api/messages', messages.update);

    app.delete('/api/messages/:id', messages.delete);
};
```

C. In `controllers/messages.js` the controller.

```
var models = require('../app/models'),
    md5 = require('MD5');

module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        models.Message.find({}, function(err, data) {
            res.json(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    },
    getById: function(req, res) {
        models.Message.find({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, message) {
            if(err)
                res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
            res.json(message);
        });
    },
    add: function(req, res) {
        var newMessage = new models.Message(req.body);
        newMessage.save(function(err, message) {
            if (err)
                res.json({});
            console.log('successfully inserted message: ' + message._id);
            res.json(message);
        });
    },

    // Again hard time with this method
    update: function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        models.Message.update({ _id: req.body.id }, req.body, function(err, updated) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
            } else {
                res.json(updated);
            }
        })
    },

    delete: function(req, res) {
        models.Message.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, message) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
            } else {
                message.remove(function(err, message){
                    res.json(200, {status: 'Success'});
                })
            }
        });
    }
};
```

D. And finally some logic to send a put request in `client/src/views/I_HAVE_A_CUSTOM_VIEW.js`

```
// Okay so my code is slightly different than the boilerplate but the idea is to 
// update a model in the collection kind of like the method below
// the method below does fire off a PUT request, but returns an error since
// my update/PUT logic is not correct
createMessage: function(data) {      

    var model = window.App.data.messages.where({username: data.username})
    _.each(model, function(model) {
        console.log(model.get('_id'));
        model.set({message: data.message})
        model.save({}, {url:'/api/messages/'+model.get('_id')})
    });

    //window.App.data.messages.create(newMessage);
    window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Add View: Saved new message!');
}
```

So this may be a tricky question, but basically I just need a little help figuring out how to write the update method in the controller so that I can successfully update a document in mongodb.

Edit: The author says he does not implement the PUT request and why here https://github.com/jkat98/benm/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add what fields you want to update. Like this (I just update the username):

```
update: function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
        models.Message.update({ _id: req.body.id }, req.body, function(err, message) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
            } else {
                message.username = req.body.username;
                message.save();
                res.json(message);
            }
        })
    },
```